# How do I get rid of the curves between the map tiles?

Tags: smooth

I am a newbie and I used the Blender GIS add on to create a 3D map in Blender using Google Maps satellite images. The area I wanted to create was large so I ended up putting different tiles together and after I inserted the elevation map these curves between the tiles appeared.

What can I do to smoothen the transition between the tiles so that it looks like a whole thing instead of being put together tile by tile?

[image]

Here's a sample:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Beluga, you'll have to give us some idea of your process.. how you made the tiles, how you put them together, otherwise we don''t have much clue about why the creases are there. Maybe share a file with 2 tiles on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, Robin. I am using this add-on called Blender GIS. First I put the satellite images together. Then using Edge Slide in Edit mode I mostly get rid of the map parts that are overlapping.  Then I combine these images with Ctrl + J and add the elevation info using the add-on. So far there are no curves. Then I convert this to mesh and extrude in Z direction in Edit mode. This is when the curves appear. Thank you, I uploaded  a sample:  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=bPbVxd7o" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/bPbVxd7o/)

Comment: Hi, beluga. Simply switching on 'Autosmooth' in the object's Data tab > Normals panel is enough to improve the appearance by preventing interpolation of normals ovet the edges of the extrusion. But that's  a symptomatic fix.. it depends what you need the result for, You may need something a bit deeper.

Comment: Oh, that is great! Thank you a lot for this! This fixes the appearance of the map which is exactly what I wanted. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Check modifiers, on and off, or maybe in shader nodes have the displacement map removed or the normal map. If it's none of that then try go in sculpt mode and smooth out the geometry with smoothing brush.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ahkai. After combining and converting the tiles into mesh I do not see any modifiers anymore. The issue starts after I extrude this mesh in Z direction to add some thickness to the map which in other case just looks like a surface. Regarding the shader nodes, I understand you mean shader editor, right? ( sorry I am new to Blender). I did not see any displacement map thing there.

Answer (score 0):

As in the Robin Betts's comment, switching on *Autosmooth* in the object's *Properties Window > Object Data > Normals* panel solved the issue for me.